# Setting environment variables for no-login users

Tags: linux, tomcat, environment-variables, bash, login-script

I have an RHEL server with tomcat installed. Tomcat runs as a no-login user called tomcat . I have set the required environment variables in  **`/etc/profile.d/myenvvars.sh`**  as

```
export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre
export MY_VAR=/usr/share/mydir
```

The environment variables are set and can be echoed in the terminal using

```
# echo $MY_VAR
# sudo -u tomcat echo $MY_VAR
```

However when tomcat starts my environment variable is not recognised by tomcat.

As per [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438150/scripts-in-etc-profile-d-being-ignored) article I found that my environment variables will not be recognised when tomcat starts as tomcat is a no-login user. Therefore I sourced the above file in  **`~/.bash_profile`**  using

```
. /etc/profile.d/myenvvars.sh
```

However, I still have the same issue, the environment variable is not reccognised.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the article your linked your settings need to be in `~/.bashrc`.

There may be a chance that even this is not working... depending on how your tomcat is started.

You could have a custom script for tomcat to make sure it loads the environment variables e.g. something like this

**tomcat-start.sh**

```
. /etc/profile.d/myenvvars.sh
tomcat
```

Comment: It's not good for production scripts to depend upon shell startup scripts like `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.  This way of putting the initializing steps in the application startup script itself is a much better practice.